# Accounts.onCreateUser not adding field to Meteor's user collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to add a new field to Meteor's user collection:

**server/fixtures.js:**

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  user.role = 'Student'
  // We still want the default hook's 'profile' behavior.
  if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
  return user
})
```

But when I do `Meteor.users.find().fetch();`:

```
Object
_id: "7zLDKQE4ACJCfeEhr"
username: "alex"
__proto__: Object
```

I don't see the field.

Isn't working in the template, either:

**documents/document_page.js:**

```
  users: function() {
    var users = _.map(Meteor.presences.find().fetch(), function(user) { 
      return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: user.userId})
    })

    return users
  },
```

**documents/user.html**

```
<template name="user">
  <li class="clearfix">
    <img src="/avatar.png"/>
    <div class="user-info">
      <p>{{userId}}</p>
      <p>{{username}}</p>
      <p>{{role}}</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</template>
```

Only username is showing. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you using alining roles package?

Comment: @Ethaan No, I just making a custom one.

Comment: i reccoment you tu use [this](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles), package, you can use html tags like `{{if isInRole 'Admin'}} Give access to this content on the html {{/if}}` // `{{if isInRole 'Super-Admin'}} Give access to this different content of html{{/if}}` on the same html, i have code example if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish the custom fields. From the docs:

> By default the server publishes username, emails, and profile (writable by user). See Meteor.users for more on the fields used in user documents.

The easiest way to do this is just to publish with a name of `null` which will automatically publish the documents without the need for a corresponding `Meteor.subscribe`:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {role: 1}});
});
```

In this case we are publishing the `role` field which will be merged with the default fields already published for the current user.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Meteor newbie. Where should I put that code? Right now I'm still using the `autopublish` package so I don't have a place where I publish my collections.

Comment: `You've set up some data subscriptions with Meteor.publish(), but
I20150128-12:27:57.115(8)? ** you still have autopublish turned on. Because autopublish is still` I guess I can only do it if I remove the `autopublish` package.

Comment: @David Weldon one question: if I put that code in a new file in my `/server/` folder, what will the `this.userId` be pointing at?

Comment: @alexchenco (1) You can ignore the warning and leave autopublish on if you want - you still need this publish to get the user fields regardless. (2) Put the publish in any file under the `server` directory - e.g. `server/publishers.js`. (3) `this.userId` will be the id of the connected user - it's automatically available to publish functions, and your publish will automatically trigger as soon as the user logs in.